# How can I check 2 conditions using let (or apply etc)

Tags: kotlin

Is there a more idiomatic way to write the following?

```
foo?.let{
        if(!foo.isBlank()) {
            bar?.let { 
                if(!bar.isBlank()) {
                    println("foo and bar both valid strings")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

basically this the idea is that both strings should be nonNull and nonEmpty and I was wondering if there is a more Kotlin way than doing `if(foo.isNullOrEmpty && !bar.isNullOrEmpty)`

Comment: scope functions cannot help you here. Kotlin encourages us to prefer concise forms first:, thus `isNullOrEmpty` is the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
fun <T, R, S> biLet(lhs: T, rhs: R, block: (T, R) -> S): S? = if (lhs != null && rhs != null) block(lhs, rhs) else null
```

Use as

```
biLet(foo, bar) { safeFoo, safeBar ->
}
```

Edit: variant for strings

```
fun <T: CharSequence?, S> biLet(lhs: T, rhs: T, block: (T, T) -> S): S? =
    if (lhs.isNotNullOrBlank() && rhs.isNotNullOrBlank()) block(lhs, rhs) else null
```

Comment: But if the check was only for `null` I could have used the `let` directly right?

Comment: You would still have to chain 2 lets, with biLet it's a single call.

Comment: But in the `biLet` implementation because it is generic I can't check for emptyness. So in the `block` I would need to add that.

Comment: Yes, this is a null safety function. You could create a variant that checks for empty string instead, I'll update the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sequenceOf` and `none`:

```
if (sequenceOf(foo, bar).none { it.isNullOrBlank() }) {
    println("foo and bar both valid strings")
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was wondering if that could work if `bar` was something other than `String`

Comment: It will work if `bar` is a subtype of `CharSequence?`. Otherwise, you won't be able to call `isNullOrBlank()` on `it`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare somewhere an extension function using lambdas like:

```
inline fun String.ifNotEmpty(bar: String, function: () -> Unit) {
    if (this.isNotEmpty() && bar.isNotEmpty()) {
        function.invoke()
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```
val foo = "foo-value"
val bar = "bar-value"

foo.ifNotEmpty(bar) {
    println("foo and bar both valid strings")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Francesc answer, I created a nLet version

```
fun <S> nLet(vararg ts: Any?, block: (Array<out Any?>) -> S): S? = 
    if (ts.none { when (it) { is String -> it.isNullOrEmpty() else -> it == null } }) block(ts) else null
```

You can use it like that

```
nLet (1, 2 , 3, "a", "B", true) { ts ->
    ts.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. It complaints on `isNullOrBlank`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
fun <P1, P2, R> nLet(p1: P1?, p2: P2?, block: (P1, P2) -> R?): R? = 
    p1?.let { p2?.let { block(p1, p2) } }
```

Usage:

```
nLet(foo, bar) { f, b -> doStuff(f, b) }
```

Add more nLet functions with more `P`'s if more arguments are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this for an arbitary number of arguments:

```
fun <P, R> nLet(vararg ts: P?, block: (Array<out P?>) -> R): R? = 
    ts.takeIf { it.none { it == null } }?.let { block(it) }
```

Usage:

```
nLet(foo, bar, dog) { (f, b, d) -> doStuff(f, b, d) }
```

This works, but `f`, `b` and `d` will have nullable types even though they cannot be null.

(There might be a clever way to solve that...)